# Avoiding creating Iterator instances in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, garbage

I need to use an iterator over an ArrayList but every time I iterate over it, it creates an Iterator instance (garbage). I need a way to iterate over the list without creating garbage.

Example:

```
for (Person person : people) {
    person.sayHi();
}
```

Comment: Why? An Iterator is a simple class with short usage, so it garbage collects very fast.

Comment: Adding to my "why?". Your `person.sayHi()` is likely doing a `System.out.println("Hello from " + this.name)`. Well, that will construct a `StringBuilder` for the concatenation, and a `String` for the result, and both of them will allocate a char array. This occurs on **every** call to `sayHi`, while the Iterator is only allocated once. In short, the Iterator is nothing.

Comment: I cannot create any garbage in my application. The example is just an example, I don't care what happens inside the loop. THE QUESTION is how to not create Iterator.

Comment: It's not garbage if you actually need it. Please demonstrate that the `Iterator` object is an actual problem.

Comment: This iteration is over hundreds of objects at an immensely high rate (1K+ iterations per second). Garbage production is sky high.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is to use Java 8.  This can use escape analysis to place the `Iterator` on the stack and thus avoid any garbage.

If you are stuck on Java 7 or older you can do this

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Person p = mlist.get(i);
```

Here is a post on why Iterator appears to be created in a profiler, but isn't when you don't run the profiler.

http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/the-escape-of-arraylistiterator.html

Comment: Thanks. Escape analysis did not seem to be immediately effective, VisualVM reports arraylist iterators are being created. In my actual code I have use ArrayList internally in a class which implements Iterable. I return the list's iterator in order to implement. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Jire VisualVM can result in some optimisation being turned off or unavailable. It also produces a lot of garbage itself. I suggest you try Java Flight Recorder.

Comment: Great, I did not know that about VisualVM. I have seen and tried JFR once upon a time, how does difficult is it to use? I did hear its performance hit is extremely low.

Comment: @Jire It's easier than it was.

Comment: @Peter If you're using an UnmodifiableList escape analysis (even in java 8) is ineffective.Probably because of the double layer of indirection.

Comment: @Dan Escape analysis may not optimise away the nested object but at least the UnmodifiableList should be optimised away (doesn't mean it will be ;)

Comment: @Peter From empirical tests I can see that the ArrayList$Itr is not escaped away.

Comment: @Dan sometimes it is. Note: some profilers will prevent escape analysis from working.

Comment: @Peter I'm using jmc FR which should ok in that respect.

Comment: does this work for `LinkedHashMap`'s `LinkedKeyIterator`? the # of instances that get created dwarfs everything else by a least a few thousand times in my code. I use Java 8.

Comment: @ycomp it can do, I suggest you use a memory profiler to check. e.g. flight recorder.

Comment: I just realized it is probably not `LinkedHashMap` doing this but `LinkedHashMultimap` - I have guava 19, hopefully updating to the latest will help

Answer (score 2):

There are really only two ways to iterate over a list:

1. Use an index [Edit for clarity -- *i.e., use a traditional **for loop***]
2. Use an iterator

[Enhanced for loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) are just syntactic sugar to avoid having to write out the code to make an `Iterator`.

Comment: The question is how can I avoid creating Iterator instances.

Comment: And the answer was provided: use the array's indices.

Comment: @Keith You probably need to spell it out for him even more: `for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) { ... }`, assuming `people` is an array since that consumes less memory than a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing your own collection that reuses *Iterator*. For some reason the Java libraries don't provide alternatives or a reused iterator (probably because they don't know what people will do with them).

Answer (score -1):

You convert from `ArrayList` to an array, then you can iterate the array by index.

Comment: Alternatively using get(index) and size(). Unfortunately I must provide an iterator for my task.

Comment: Creating an array, to copy the arraylist into, is much worse for memory allocation and garbage collection than creating the iterator and using it!